# MacOS 'Big Sur' bad cpu type in executable error

Tags: error, cpu

I'm trying to follow along with this simple tutorial (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) to install Flutter SDK on my new MacOS. I reach step 3 which is to run the program "Flutter Doctor" by typing "Flutter Doctor" in the terminal. I am then greeted with the following error:

```
/Users/Jake/documents/flutter/bin/flutter: line 183: 
/Users/jake/documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: Bad CPU type in executable
```

I've tried using different versions of flutter and still get the following error.

I'm running a MacBook Pro with M1 if it helps.

Edit: could apples new CPU be the issue?

Comment: Yes.  You should confirm if flutter supports ARM/M1 Architecture